# Set invalid input to initial value

Tags: jquery

I have a input which on change send its value via ajax and it is saved into db. I need to prevent sending empty value or value which is not numeric and should be or vice versa. So I am calling ajax function after few if/else blocks. This works ok, but is possible set invalid changed input to previous value? For example I have a input with value "456321". User change it to "abcde". It is not numeric so it isn't send to the server but I need change value back to "456321".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a Hidden Field which will be filled with the initial value.
Suppose you have value "4321" to be shown in the text box. Just load that value Into the textbox as well as in hidden field. Now on Change of this value when you are making an AJAX request, So if the value is correct just update the hidden field with the correct value else just replace the value in the textbox with the value in the hidden field. Hope this helps...

Sample Code:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="1234"/>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="1234"/>

$('#textbox').change(function(){
    if(parseInt($('#textbox').val()))
       {
           $('#hidden').val($('#textbox').val());
           //Make AJAX request
       }
       else
       {
           $('#textbox').val($('#hidden').val());
       }
});
```